# Best way to extract vim syntax files and ctags from Doxygen?

Tags: vim, doxygen, ctags

I wanted to write a vim syntax file for a library that has Doxygen documentation.

Does a tool like that already exist ?

If not, what would be the best way to generate this automatically ?

- write a new output generator (complicated) ?
- parse lots of xml from doxygen/xml/*.xml (slow) ?

Anything else ?

I was surprised that something like this doesn't already exist.  Any idea why ? Am I looking in the wrong place ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extract ctags from the .h files?

Comment: What would the syntax files do?  Highlight known function names?

Comment: In this particular case it's for nxc, Not Exactly C, used for Mindstorms, and I am not sure if it's close enough to C for this.

Answer (score 2):

As opposed to parsing all of the generated XML files, you should be able to generate a Doxygen tags file. The tag file can be created with the Doxygen option `GENERATE_TAGFILE`. The resulting file is still XML, but it captures all of the files, structs, functions and other symbols in a single file which is likely easier to transform into the format that you need.